# Filterdefinition with an array parameter (SQL: WHERE IN)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Right now I have a FilterDefinition with this:

```
public class PurposeFilter:FilterDefinition
{
    public PurposeFilter()
        : base(NHibernateFilters.PurposeFilter, "PurposeId = :purposeId",
        new Dictionary<string, IType> { { "purposeId", NHibernateUtil.Int64 } }, false)
    {}
}
```

This adds a `WHERE PurposeId = <someId>` to the SQL generated. However, I would like to add support for multiple Ids, so the resulting SQL would be `WHERE PurposeId IN (<someId>, <someOtherId>)`. I have the following code (that does not work) - any suggestions on how to support this?

```
public class MultiPurposeFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public MultiPurposeFilter()
        : base(NHibernateFilters.MultiPurposeFilter, "PurposeId IN (purposeIds)"
            , new Dictionary<string, IType> { { "purposeIds", NHibernateUtil.Int64 } }, false)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "PurposeId IN (:purposeIds)" and `SetParameterList` method to set the values?

Comment: @Najera: That was simple... and it works... Thank you! Please convert your comment to an answer and I will approve it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Haven't tried yet, but you can use `PurposeId IN (:purposeIds)` and `SetParameterList` method to set the values.